# How to remove artifactItems from maven before the build

Tags: maven, maven-2, mvn-repo

My maven pom looks like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>x</groupId>
    <artifactId>x</artifactId>
    <version>x</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>x</groupId>
  <artifactId>x</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>x</id>
      <url>x</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-web</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>xx.xx.xx</groupId>
                  <artifactId>xx</artifactId>
                  <version>xx</version>
                  <classifier>release</classifier>
                </artifactItem>

                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>xx.xx.xx</groupId>
                  <artifactId>xx</artifactId>
                  <version>xx</version>
                  <type>war</type>
                </artifactItem>

                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>xx.xx.xx</groupId>
                  <artifactId>xx</artifactId>
                  <version>xx</version>
                  <type>war</type>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <outputDirectory>/target/output</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I wanted to delete the mentioned artifact items before performing the build so that it downloads the latest versions from repository.

The current behaviour is that, if a version is present in the local repository, it is not checking whether a newer version is present or not.

I tried -U option && purge dependency option but did not wprk

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of problem your are trying to solve with this maven-dependency-plugin configuration but it looks wrong to me...What kind of dependencies do you have ? Releases or snapshots?

Comment: Those are releases.
Step 1 - Many projects build release artifacts and deploy them to remote repos
Step 2 - There is this final build for which I had shared the pom file. This build will get all these artifact items. But the problem is that it is not taking the latest ones' from the remote repos. Instead it is just copying from the local m2 repo

Comment: It will not take cause you have defined appropriate versions in your pom (configuration)...but why are you copying those files into `target/output`? looks wrong in particular in `generate-resources` phase?

Comment: This pom is a separate project which packages all of the components together into a big binary file. It is not picking the latest artifacts from remote repos. Instead it is using the existing artifacts in m2-repo